# How to make WebStorm not wrap identifier in parentheses when I type .par and hit tab

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

If I type `xxx.par` and hit `tab`, it becomes `(xxx)`. What is the name of this feature, How can I turn it off?

It's quite annoying because I constantly getting `(JSON)` and `(req)` while what I really want is `JSON.parse()` and `req.params`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is called code completion in WebStorm.

There are 2 issues from your question:

First is to disable auto-completion for xxx.par

You may turn it off via Settings | Editor | General | Postfix Completion | uncheck "par"

The second issue is about disabling auto-completion for all variables.

Settings | Editor | General | Code completion | 
and uncheck "Smart Type Completion" and "Auto-display code completion"